# Why is writing to a 24-bit struct not atomic (when writing to a 32-bit struct appears to be)?

Tags: c#, struct, alignment, atomic, value-type

I am a tinkerer—no doubt about that. For this reason (and very little beyond that), I recently did a little experiment to confirm my suspicion that writing to a `struct` is not an atomic operation, which *means* that a so-called "immutable" value type which attempts to enforce certain constraints could hypothetically fail at its goal.

I wrote [a blog post about this](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/beware-assignment-atomic-assignment/) using the following type as an illustration:

```
struct SolidStruct
{
    public SolidStruct(int value)
    {
        X = Y = Z = value;
    }

    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public readonly int Z;
}
```

While the above *looks* like a type for which it could never be true that `X != Y` or `Y != Z`, in fact this *can* happen if a value is "mid-assignment" at the same time it is copied to another location by a separate thread.

OK, big deal. A curiosity and little more. But then I had this hunch: my 64-bit CPU *should* actually be able to copy 64 bits atomically, right? So what if I got rid of `Z` and just stuck with `X` and `Y`? That's only 64 bits; it should be possible to overwrite those in one step.

**Sure enough, it worked.** (I realize some of you are probably furrowing your brows right now, thinking, *Yeah, duh. How is this even interesting?* Humor me.) Granted, I have no idea whether this is guaranteed or not given my system. I know next to nothing about registers, cache misses, etc. (I am literally just regurgitating terms I've heard without understanding their meaning); so this is all a black box to me at the moment.

The next thing I tried—again, just on a hunch—was a struct consisting of 32 bits using 2 `short` fields. This seemed to exhibit "atomic assignability" as well. But *then* I tried a 24-bit struct, using 3 `byte` fields: **no go**.

Suddenly the struct appeared to be susceptible to "mid-assignment" copies once again.

Down to 16 bits with 2 `byte` fields: atomic again!

Could someone explain to me why this is? I've heard of "bit packing", "cache line straddling", "alignment", etc.—but again, I don't really know what all that means, nor whether it's even relevant here. But I *feel* like I see a pattern, without being able to say exactly what it is; clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The CLI spec makes guarantees for atomicity for 1, 2 and 4 byte memory accesses on 32-bit targets, 8 byte on 64-bit targets, but only if the variable is properly aligned.  This doesn't cover structures, you can screw them up by using StructLayout.Pack.

Comment: For anyone who found this while searching for multithreading questions, you shouldn't rely on CPU atomicity for thread safety.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is the native word size of the CPU.

Historically, the x86 family worked natively with 16-bit values (and before that, 8-bit values). For that reason, your CPU can handle these atomically: it's a single instruction to set these values.

As time progressed, the native element size increased to 32 bits, and later to 64 bits. In every case, an instruction was added to handle this specific amount of bits. However, for backwards compatibility, the old instructions were still kept around, so your 64-bit processor can work with all of the previous native sizes.

Since your struct elements are stored in contiguous memory (without padding, i.e. empty space), the runtime can exploit this knowledge to only execute that single instruction for elements of these sizes. Put simply, that creates the effect you're seeing, because the CPU can only execute one instruction at a time (although I'm not sure if true atomicity can be guaranteed on multi-core systems).

However, the native element size was never 24 bits. Consequently, there is no single instruction to write 24 bits, so multiple instructions are required for that, and you lose the atomicity.

Comment: Awesome—you learn something new every day! Sometimes many things. Thanks for the historical explanation.

Comment: @Dan: You've probably figured this out thanks to your experiment with the 24-bit structure, but this is not something you should rely on. It's better to do proper locking, because although it's unlikely that the runtime would stop using this optimization, proper locking protects you in case the size of your struct ever needs to change.

Answer (score 6):

The C# standard ([ISO 23270:2006](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042926_ISO_IEC_23270_2006%28E%29.zip), [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)) has this to say regarding atomicity:

> **12.5 Atomicity of variable references**
> Reads and writes of the following data types shall be atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort,
> uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type
> in the previous list shall also be atomic. **Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double,
> and decimal, as well as user-defined types, need not be atomic.** (*emphasis mine*) Aside from the library functions designed
> for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or
> decrement.

Your example `X = Y = Z = value` is short hand for 3 separate assignment operations, each of which is defined to be atomic by 12.5. The sequence of 3 operations (assign `value` to `Z`, assign `Z` to `Y`, assign `Y` to `X`) is **not** guaranteed to be atomic.

Since the language specification doesn't mandate atomicity, while `X = Y = Z = value;`  **might** be an atomic operation, whether it is or not is dependent on a whole bunch of factors:

- the whims of the compiler writers
- what code generation optimizations options, if any, were selected at build time
- the details of the JIT compiler responsible for turning the assembly's IL into machine language. Identical IL run under Mono, say, might exhibit different behaviour than when run under .Net 4.0 (and that might even differ from earlier versions of .Net).
- the particular CPU on which the assembly is running.

One might also note that even a single machine instruction is not necessarily warranted to be an atomic operation—many are interruptable.

Further, visiting the CLI standard ([ISO 23217:2006](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042927_ISO_IEC_23271_2006%28E%29.zip)), we find section 12.6.6:

> **12.6.6 Atomic reads and writes**
>   A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to properly
>   aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size (the size of type
>   `native int`) is atomic (see §12.6.2) when all the write accesses to a location are
>   the same size. Atomic writes shall alter no bits other than those written. Unless
>   explicit layout control (see Partition II (Controlling Instance Layout)) is used to
>   alter the default behavior, data elements no larger than the natural word size (the
>   size of a `native int`) shall be properly aligned. Object references shall be treated
>   as though they are stored in the native word size.
>
> [***Note:* There is no guarantee
>   about atomic update (read-modify-write) of memory, except for methods provided for
>   that purpose as part of the class library (see Partition IV).** (*emphasis mine*)
>   An atomic write of a “small data item” (an item no larger than the native word size)
>   *is* required to do an atomic read/modify/write on hardware that does not support direct
>   writes to small data items. *end note*]
>
> [*Note:* There is no guaranteed atomic access to 8-byte data when the size of
>   a native int is 32 bits even though some implementations might perform atomic
>   operations when the data is aligned on an 8-byte boundary. *end note*]

Comment: Very helpful and informative answer in general... I do just have one comment, which is that unless I'm mistaken, the lack of atomicity I've described in the question is *not* related to the `X = Y = Z = value` assignment. It is rather the result of a "copy out" (assignment to the local variable on the background thread) occurring *at the same time* as a "copy in" (assignment to the static field on the main thread). Forgive me if those are poorly chosen terms (probably); in any case, does that make sense?

Comment: @Dan Tao: correct.  The atomicity of the multipart assignment x = y = z = value is only an issue if something is writing to value in another thread at the same time. Since value in your example above is a function parameter, it is a local variable and not accessible by any other thread so this is not an issue in your particular example. The value will not change during the multipart assignment.  And since this assignment is made in the constructor, nobody else can see this instance yet so there is no issue of observers seeing the properties in an inconsistent state during the assignment.

Comment: Which brings you back to ISO 23270 section 12.5 (which see above): "Reads and writes of...user-defined [value] types, need not be atomic."

Answer (score 4):

x86 CPU operations take place in 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits; manipulating other sizes requires multiple operations.

Comment: OK, this is probably a dumb question, but: would it therefore make sense to "pad" a value type up to one of those numbers of bits (with throwaway `byte` fields) if it's intended to be used in a high-performance scenario?

Comment: 64-bit read/writes are not atomic on x86, they can straddle a cache line boundary.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler and x86 CPU are going to be careful to move only exactly as many bytes as the structure defines.  There are no x86 instructions that can move 24 bits in one operation, but there are single instruction moves for 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit data.

If you add another byte field to your 24 bit struct (making it a 32 bit struct), you should see your atomicity return.

Some compilers allow you to define padding on structs to make them behave like native register sized data.  If you pad your 24 bit struct, the compiler will add another byte to "round up" the size to 32 bits so that the whole structure can be moved in one atomic instruction.  The downside is your structure will always occupy 30% more space in memory.

Note that alignment of the structure in memory is also critical to atomicity.  If a multibyte structure does not begin at an aligned address, it may span multiple cache lines in the CPU cache.  Reading or writing this data will require multiple clock cycles and multiple read/writes even though the opcode is a single move instruction.  So, even single instruction moves may not be atomic if the data is misaligned. x86 does guarantee atomicity for native sized read/writes on aligned boundaries, even in multicore systems.

It is possible to achieve memory atomicity with multi-step moves using the x86 LOCK prefix.  However this should be avoided as it can be very expensive in multicore systems (LOCK not only blocks other cores from accessing memory, it also locks the system bus for the duration of the operation which can impact disk I/O and video operations.  LOCK may also force the other cores to purge their local caches)